# What is a "professional" synonym for newbie?

Tags: synonyms

At one of my past jobs, I trained 4 team members who joined as college graduates, and they took on important assignments in a relatively short time. I want to write this as an achievement in my resume used to apply to a leadership role.

> Trained 4 *newbies* to become key contributors

obviously isn't "professional" to be written in a resume. I looked up thesaurus.com for synonyms but the words that I found (freshman, novice, rookie) suffer from the same problem.

What is a good "professional" synonym for newbie?

PS: This is beyond the scope of this question, but if there is a better wording to describe the above achievement (without being overly verbose or obscure), I would like to know it as well.

Comment: I think *novice* is fine. Some other possible alternatives are *beginner*, *new recruit*, and *newcomer*. (They aren't quite exactly the same thing, though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One of my more important responsibilities was as Training Officer. I
>   successfully trained four new team members who quickly proved capable
>   of taking on important assignments.

Compare that to:

> Trained four new team members to become key contributors.

If you were the employer, which would you prefer to see?
Even if you only trained them to use a sweeping brush, it doesn't really matter. Never be afraid to apply a little spin when it comes to selling yourself.

New staff or new employees would work just as well if you don't like, new team members.